# What is TN rate in Weka results?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I have a question about classifications model in Weka.
Which parameters in the result from weka is the TN rate(specificity)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not reported. But, it can be directly calculated from the false positive rate, as the following relation holds between them: $\text{TNR}=1-\text{FPR}$.